# block display of drawer and main content in paper-drawer-panel

Tags: css, polymer-1.0

For the code below, I am expecting the drawer and main toolbars to be aligned horizontally. The are aligned vertically instead! Please help me sort this out.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link ref="import" href="polymer/polymer.html" />
  <link ref="import" href="paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="paper-styles/paper-styles.html" />

</head>

<body unresolved>
  <paper-drawer-panel>

    <paper-header-panel drawer>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <span>My drawer</span>
      </paper-toolbar>
    </paper-header-panel>

    <paper-header-panel main>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <span>My content</span>
      </paper-toolbar>
    </paper-header-panel>

  </paper-drawer-panel>
</body>

</html>
```

[rendered html with toolbars aligned vertically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCNq4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using ref instead of **rel** for `polymer` and `paper-drawer-panel`. Polymer is still getting imported as it is dependency in other modules, but drawer-panel is not imported as all

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <base href="https://polygit.org/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="paper-scroll-header-panel/paper-scroll-header-panel.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icon/iron-icon.html" />
  <link rel="import" href="paper-styles/paper-styles.html" />

</head>

<body unresolved>
  <paper-drawer-panel>

    <paper-header-panel drawer>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <span>My drawer</span>
      </paper-toolbar>
    </paper-header-panel>

    <paper-header-panel main>
      <paper-toolbar>
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <span>My content</span>
      </paper-toolbar>
    </paper-header-panel>

  </paper-drawer-panel>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: omg thanks! which editor/ide who you recommend to use in order to catch misspelled html attributes etc. I am currently using atom with some plugins installed.

Comment: You can use any editor like brackets, atom or vs code. Later two have inbuilt snippets and for former you can use `emmet` for snippets.